Google Address Autocomplete Dropdown Won't Go Away After A Selection Is Made
I'm trying to use Google Address Autocomplete inside of a form. The autocomplete functionality works but when a selection is made the dropdown menu remains on the screen and I would like it to go away.
Below is the code I'm using. I've tried many things but nothing seems to work properly.
<script>
    var input = document.querySelector('input[name="address"]');
    var options = {
        types: ['address'] // Set to autocomplete only address types
    };

    // Initialize Google Places Autocomplete for the input field
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    // Listen for the place_changed event
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        if (place && place.formatted_address) {
            // Populate the input field with the full address
            input.value = place.formatted_address;

            // Dispatch an input event to ensure other listeners pick up the changes
            input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

            // Save the address info to sessionStorage if needed
            var addressInfo = {
                address: place.formatted_address
            };
            sessionStorage.setItem('addressInfo', JSON.stringify(addressInfo));
        } else {
            console.log("No address found for the selected place.");
        }

        // Close the dropdown immediately
        closeDropdown();
    });

    // Function to close the autocomplete dropdown
    function closeDropdown() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            input.blur(); // This should close the dropdown
        }, 200); // Slight delay to ensure place is selected
    }

    // Disable browser's autocomplete and manage focus behavior
    input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        input.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'); // Disable browser's autocomplete
    });

    // Handle clicks outside the input to close dropdown
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (!input.contains(event.target) && document.querySelector('.pac-container')) {
            input.blur(); // Close the dropdown if clicked outside
        }
    });

    // Populate address fields from sessionStorage on load (if needed)
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var addressInfo = getAddressInfo();
        if (addressInfo) {
            input.value = addressInfo.address; // Populate the address field
            input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); // Dispatch event to trigger listeners
        }
    });

    function getAddressInfo() {
        var addressInfo = sessionStorage.getItem('addressInfo');
        return addressInfo ? JSON.parse(addressInfo) : null;
    }
</script>
     


but nothing seems to work properly.: please describe specifically how your code is not working as expected. What steps have you taken to debug it? Also, please include the relevant html, and any other additional code or libraries required in order to create a [mre].
